# Share a folder with files

Tags: pages, directory

I<sup>*</sup> would like to have a page with a weblink when clicked it would show a simple folder structure with folders and files, and visitors can download those files.

Similar to this [UCSC website](http://hgdownload.soe.ucsc.edu/goldenPath/hg19/). It should also be possible to download via full path to the file without going through the main page, like this example:

```
wget http://hgdownload.soe.ucsc.edu/goldenPath/hg19/UCSCGenes/uniProtToUcscGenes.txt
```

If possible, I would want to avoid plugins, if not please also advise on suitable plugins.

---

System info:

```
WordPress 4.4.2    
Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-97-generic x86_64)
```

---

<sup>*</sup> First time post, kindly let me know if there is a duplicated post, or my post needs more clarification in the comments. Pretty sure I used wrong search words to find relevant posts.

Comment: Are you wanting to manage the files through WordPress? Or is this a completely standalone folder of files? If it's standalone, you can accomplish completely outside of WP - just create a folder via FTP, add your files, and set .htaccess to allow directory listing for just that folder. Then link from your WP site to the folder where all the files are, and it will automatically list all the files with links to download. Files by default will be directly downloadable as well.

Comment: @WebElaine can be either within or outside wp, but on the same server. Could you explain in more detail (sorry, I am new to wp), and post as an answer, I will then have a go and try out?